Can you specify exactly which line of code a phpunit test should cover?
Considering that there are 2 cases which would have the same result, is there an annotation or anything I can add to make sure that my test covers a specific line in a function?

Given that code, I want to be sure that this test is hitting the second condition rather than the first.

Is this possible or should I just pull that case into a very specific function to make sure that is what is being covered?

"Is this possible or should I just pull that case into a very specific function to make sure that is what is being covered?" - The latter is what I would recommend. Alternatively, is it possible to have a dedicated tag for that condition?

The test should not know anything about the code and should not be validating any specific execution path. Simply assert that it returns what you expect. Which line generates the output is irrelevant if the output is correct. By forcing it to look at a specific execution path, you're limiting your ability to refactor.

It's easier to arrive at the kinds of tests that @AlexHowansky is referring to if you start by writing a test, before writing the production code. That way, you're biased by the expected behaviour rather than the implementation of that behaviour.

To be clear, I am a big advocate of doing test-driven development.

Hey @ChrisHaas thanks for the recommendation, what I was able to do is pass it as an array from the second addTag call since the Zendesk function allows arrays or strings so I just changed the shouldReceive call to expect an array and I was able to target that specific call.
